# Model Binding with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to make a simple todo MVC application with asp.net core MVC. My plan is to make a webpage with simple checkboxes and give the user the ability to change the state with a form. 
The form is displayed correctly but the "model binding" in the controller does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

[The UI (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiLp9.png)

The view:

```
@model List<Todo>

<form  asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ModifyTodo" method="post">

    <ul class="mdc-list">
        @for (var i = 0; i <  Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <li class="mdc-list-item">

                <input asp-for="@Model[i].Status" name="todos[@i].Status" >
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].Id" name="todos[@i].Id" value="@Model[i].Id" type="hidden">
                <input asp-for="@Model[i].Text" name="todos[@i].Text" value="@Model[i].Text" type="hidden">

                <label> @Model[i].Text</label>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return GiveTodoView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ModifyTodo([FromForm] List<Todo> todos)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(test);
        var temp = "Count: "+todos.Count;
        foreach (var todo in todos)
        {
            temp += todo.Status + " " + todo.Text + " <br />";
        }
        return Content(temp);
        //   return GiveTodoView();
    }

    private IActionResult GiveTodoView()
    {
        var manager = TodoManager.GetTotalManager();

        return View("Index", manager.GetTodos().ToList());
    }
}
```

Todo.cs

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id;
    public bool Status;
    public string Text;
}
```

How do I get all my todo's from the form back in my controller's action `ModifyTodo`?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

The html generated by Razor. I've stripped the unnecessary markup

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/ModifyTodo">
    <ul class="mdc-list">
            <li class="mdc-list-item">

                <input name="todos[0].Status" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Boolean field is required." id="z0__Status" value="true">
                <input name="todos[0].Id" value="0" type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="z0__Id">
                <input name="todos[0].Text" value="First test" type="hidden" id="z0__Text">
                <label>First test</label></li>
            <li class="mdc-list-item">

                    <input name="todos[1].Status" type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Boolean field is required." id="z1__Status" value="true">
                    <input name="todos[1].Id" value="0" type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Int32 field is required." id="z1__Id">
                    <input name="todos[1].Text" value="second test" type="hidden" id="z1__Text">
                <label>second test</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8GAD8c4qIkNEktrZwHPVewBTkkBNZ7RlAVcu7N2_sgbMy2O3FSRi_x5Nw1WNlXWqBhz_wNdeBYCj9oqnopS4fZxDgvjC5FGeCQ2jS3tS7IdXgwyAxPe6BnDhmOJDcK9fmqBdV8BcTC8qxrZEouj4RMU" />
<input name="[0].Status" type="hidden" value="false">
<input name="[1].Status" type="hidden" value="false">
</form>
```

Comment: what's the html that's getting generated from your razor?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: Start by removing your pointless `name` and `value` attributes. Never set those when using the `asp-for` helpers - they already add the correct `name` and `value` attributes (and the correct `name` attributes to bind to `List<todos>` are `name="[0].Status"` , `name="[0].Id"` etc.

Comment: And the reason your model does not bind is because it contains only fields, not properties (and the ModelBinder does not bind fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `todos` is the name of the root object you want to bind to you don't need its name on the inputs

```
<input asp-for="@Model[i].Status" name="[@i].Status" >
```

You also need to change these from public fields to public properties

```
public class Todo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's no point in using a tag helper if you're going to explicitly set the name attribute. Your answer would be acceptable with the `asp-for` bit removed, but then the name is being hard-coded, which is not ideal.

Comment: There is a point actually. To override what you want the name attribute to be.

Comment: The form values are posted like this now: [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Yzp.png) . But still it is not recognised.

Comment: @Shoe. That's the *entire* point of the helper: to create a name that can be bound properly. Either use the helper or set an explicit name attribute; not both.

Comment: @ChrisPratt asp-for will also set the id, value, and any dataannotations you have on the property. So no, not the *entire* point of the helper

Comment: @Carlo Found your other problem. See the updated answer

Comment: @Shoe Thanks! It works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You're prefixing your `asp-for` values with an `@`. This will cause Razor to actually get the value of that property, and place it there. That's not what you want. Instead, your tag helpers should be formatted as:

```
<input asp-for="[i].Status">
```

Comment: This doesn't compile fyi

Comment: It doens't work unfortunately. It does generate better HTML. But the "model binding" is still broken.

Comment: Try `[i].Status`, instead. I wasn't sure about the `Model` part being in there, as I haven't tried yet to post a collection as the actual model via tag helpers before. For other types of properties, you wouldn't include the `Model` part, but `[i].Status` just looked weird to me as an expression.

Comment: No, because in that scenario we are no longer working with a specific object, just an index accessor and a property that doesn't belong to the accessor