# How to submit multiple checkbox selections containing existing selections and save the newly modified items in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have a model called `Course` and another model called `SelectedCourse`. These two models represent two different tables and have exclusive properties to their own and hence not the same type.

I would like to display `List<Course>` on my page in the form of multiple check-boxes. The courses that are available in the `List<SelectedCourse>` should be marked as checked.

How do I build my ViewModel to achieve this?

For Post, I would like to return the list of my ViewModel back to the controller and the POST action. And then be able to only delete/add the items that were modified (selected/un-selected) to the table representing `List<SelectedCourse>`.

How do I achieve this?

(Because I don't know how to create my ViewModel, I cannot provide cshtml or controller actions to prove effort)

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel could contain a list of e.g. `CourseViewModel` objects, which contains the properties of the `Course` you are using in the view, but also a `bool` for representing whether the course is selected. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555543/how-do-i-implement-a-checkbox-list-in-asp-net-core) for an example.

Your action method (POST) could take the list of `CourseViewModels` as argument, which allows the form to post that list of ViewModels back to the controller. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526433/model-binding-with-asp-net-core) for an example.